# SoapClient: Unable to find the wrapper "https"

Tags: php, soap

I am having serious trouble trying to get this url to load in my code. When I go to the actual page in the browser it loads fine, but when I parse it its basically giving a 404, I have tried this using soap client and curl thinking ok maybe im doing something wrong.

This is my code, you can see its the bare basics.

```
$customerId = 'xxxx';
$authenticationId = 'xxxx';
$url = 'https://test.api.800loanmart.com/LoanmartService.svc?wsdl';
$config = array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 0);

$service = new SoapClient($url,$config);
$result = $service->GetTermsAndConditions($customerId, $authenticationId);
var_dump($service);
```

and this is what it is throwing back at me...

```
Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\xampp\htdocs\loanmart\index.php on line 6

Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://test.api.800loanmart.com/LoanmartService.svc?wsdl" in C:\xampp\htdocs\loanmart\index.php on line 6

Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://test.api.800loanmart.com/LoanmartService.svc?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://test.api.800loanmart.com/LoanmartService.svc?wsdl" in C:\xampp\htdocs\loanmart\index.php on line 6
```

I have checked to see if I have openssl and it is turned on in my php.ini file, im just pretty stumped as to what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Simple issue that gave me headaches! Open your php.ini file in your apache server directory and uncomment(enable) the line `extension=php_openssl.dll`.

This fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you did check, this is nothing but an openssl configuration issue (used in SoapClient, but still)

Try to `file_get_contents($wsdl_url);`

Also, check your currently loaded php.ini & supported streams (php.ini might differs from CLI to web SAPI)

```
php -r "phpinfo();" > file.txt
```

Mine :
Registered PHP Streams => php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, https, ftps, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
(your code sample works on my computer :p)

Answer (score 0):

make active extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini. Restart server.